# Using whereRaw condition on laravel eager loading with query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

We want's to need those complain, which lifetime(created_at - now()) is grater then a complain lifetime(the lifetime amount stored on complain_type table) by eloquent relationship.

**01.complain table:**

```
+---+------------+-----------------+
|id | complain_preset_id  | created_at      |
+---+------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 48         | 3/16/2018 10:30 |
| 2 | 13         | 3/16/2018 10:43 |
| 3 | 12         | 3/16/2018 10:57 |
+---+------------+-----------------+
```

**02. Complain Preset Table:**

```
+---+------------+-----------------+
|id | type_id    | created_at      |
+---+------------+-----------------+
| 1 |  1         |  3/16/2018 6:29 |
| 2 |  2         |  3/16/2018 6:29 |
| 3 |  3         |  3/16/2018 6:29 |
+---+------------+-----------------+
```

**03. complain type table**

```
+---+------------+
|id | lifetime   |
+---+------------+
| 1 |  10        |
| 2 |  36        |
| 3 |  360       |
| 4 |  500       |
+---+------------+
```

> the relation between complain->preset is:

```
public function preset()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ComplainPreset::class, 'complain_preset_id');
}
```

> the relation between preset->complain is:

```
public function complains()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Complain::class, 'complain_id');
}
```

> AND preset->complain_type:

```
public function complainType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ComplainType::class, 'type_id');
}
```

> complain_type->preset:

```
public function presets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ComplainPreset::class);
}
```

Their is no direct relationship between complain to complain_type.

Here is our solution eloquent query. but that query doesn't work.

**The relation is complain->preset->complain_type**

```
Complain::with(['preset' => function ($q) {
    $q->with(['complainType' => function($q2) {
        $q2->whereRaw('SUBTIME(NOW(), lifetime) > complains.created_at');
    }]);
}])->whereDate('created_at', '=' , Carbon::today());
```

In line 3, this query didn't get complains.created_at, because this line refer to complain_type table. 
On line 3 we need to access complains.created_at.

**Is their any eloquent way ?**

Comment: Do you want to filter `Complain` data or to filter the data of  eager loaded data only?

Comment: we want to filter the `complain` data @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: We want's to return this query, because we later we add some other where condition for other filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Complain::whereHas('preset.complainType', function($query) {
    $query->whereRaw('SUBTIME(NOW(), lifetime) > complains.created_at');
})->whereDate('complains.created_at', '=', Carbon::today());
```

Answer (score 2):

> We want's to need those complain

You could use join to apply filter using column of main table `complains` with your indirectly (via complain_preset) related table `complain_type`

```
Complain::with('preset')
        ->join('complain_preset as cs','complains.complain_preset_id','=', 'cs.id')
        ->join('complain_type as ct','cs.type_id','=', 'ct.id')
        ->whereRaw('SUBTIME(NOW(), ct.lifetime) > complains.created_at')
        ->whereDate('complains.created_at', '=' , Carbon::today());
```

Comment: thank you very much, probably this can solve our problem, but is any eloquent solution in this problem?